# Can't access an object's property in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vue-component, javascript-objects

I can't access an object in Vue, here's the code:

App:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <HeaderComp title="Task Tracker"></HeaderComp>
    <TasksComp :tasks="tasks"></TasksComp>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderComp from "./components/Header.vue";
import TasksComp from "./components/Tasks.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HeaderComp,
    TasksComp,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    const promise = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then(
      (res) => res.json()
    );
    const handle = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await promise;
        this.tasks = data;
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    handle();
  },
};
</script>
```

Tasks:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task">
      <TaskComp :task="task"></TaskComp>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import TaskComp from "./Task.vue";

export default {
  name: "TasksComp",
  props: ["tasks"],
  components: {
    TaskComp,
  },
};
</script>
```

Task:

```
  <p>{{ task.body }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TaskComp",
  props: ["task"],
};
</script>
```

I have fetched and handled a JSON and parsed it into a JavaScript Object and passed it as a data item to the array tasks in data(). In Tasks.vue, I have looped over each element (basically only one, which is called data that stores an object) now named as task in tasks. Now, Task.vue will have a prop passed from Tasks.vue called task which equals the task element (fetched data). In the paragraph that is inside the Task.vue file, I access the prop task and its property called body.

Now, after all this, I should be able to see the content that the body property stores, although, that doesn't happen.

What is the issue here? Thank you for all the answers in the comments.

I checked whether body was a valid property, I have checked for any potential type coercions and syntax errors, names, and tried to solve this issue with ChatGPT, but to no avail.

Comment: You expect an array of tasks but get a single task. You should see that in a console

Comment: I don't understand the parts of code. I see Tasks and Task with the same name  "TasksComp".... I think that there are mistaces in components.  The Tasks uses TaskComp, but there isn't reference of <Tasks> anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You defined `tasks` as an array. But you receive an object from the API. Instead of settings a new value on the tasks array you have to push it to the array.

```js
const handle = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await promise;
    this.tasks.push(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```